# read part of the file using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

How can an array be read from a file? I have a `Student` class and I need to fill in its fields where the `marks` field is an array. I'm trying to fill it in. I need to do it using the stream API. Maybe there is an easier way to make it using the stream API? How do I fix my code?

```java
class Lesson_Stream6 {
//        # Name Surname Marks
//        1 Mike Scott [4,5,5]
//        2 Joe Jones [1,2,3]
//        3 Ann Fleming [3,3,3]
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path1 = "C:\\Users\\Professional\\IdeaProjects\\Lesson\\src\\StreamAPI\\FileStream";
        List<String> stream1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(path1)).toList();
        String[] arr =  new String[stream1.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < stream1.size(); i++) {
            arr[i] = stream1.get(i);
        }        
        List<Student6>student4s = Stream.of(arr)
                                        .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
                                        .map( l -> {
                                                    String s = l.split(" ")[3];
                                                    String[] chars = s.split("");
                                                    Integer[] integers = new Integer[3];
                                                    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                                                        if (chars[i].matches("[0-9]")) {
                                                            int c = 0;
                                                            integers[c++] = Integer.parseInt(chars[i]);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    out.println(Arrays.toString(integers));
                                                    return new Student6(Integer.parseInt(l.split(" ")[0]),
                                                                        l.split(" ")[1],
                                                                        l.split(" ")[2],
                                                                        new Integer[]{1, 1, 1});
                                         })
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        out.println(student4s.get(1).Name);
    }
}

class Student6 {
    int ID;
    String Name;
    String Surname;
    Integer [] marks;

    public Student6(int ID, String name, String surname, Integer[] marks) {
        this.ID = ID;
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        this.marks = marks;
    }
}
```

Comment: *Which* part of the file do you want to read? Please show example contents of the file you want to read by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: It seams like this won't work and you would be getting a `List<Stream<String>>` out.

Comment: _I want to write only names to the list_ what did you try to achieve that?

Comment: just replace your `.map` with something like this: `.map(line -> {String arr = line.split(" "); return "%s %s".formatted(arr[1], arr[2]); })`

Comment: @EmanuelTrandafir `"%s %s".formatted(arr[1], arr[2])` is an obfuscated and expensive way to get the same as a straight-forward `arr[1] + " " +arr[2]`

Comment: Re your edit, this question is already closed, so nobody will see it, and in any case a question here should not contain two more more sub-questions.

Comment: I corrected my question. deleted the question that was before. is that okay?

Comment: @RZav if you have a new question then you can make a new question. It still needs to be a good question otherwise it will get closed. It's a bit confusing because you posted the same code.

Comment: good. I will create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you.

```
public class Lesson_Stream6  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> fileLine = new ArrayList<>();
        fileLine.add("# Name Surname Marks");
        fileLine.add("1 Mike Scott [4,5,5]");
        fileLine.add("2 Joe Jones [1,2,3]");
        fileLine.add("3 Ann Fleming [3,3,3]");

        List<String> nameLine = fileLine.stream()
                .skip(1) // ignore the first element
                .map(l -> l.split(" ")[1]) // extract target String
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collect

        nameLine.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Comment: and if not a list is given, but a file. how to read from a file?

Comment: fileLine = stream
                    .filter(line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
                    .map(l -> l.split(" ")[1])
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: Why would you replace the `.filter` call with a `.skip(1)` seems to be a bit of a downgrade.