# read part(array) of the file using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

how can an array be read from a file? I have a Student class, I need to fill in its fields, the "marks" field is an array, I'm trying to fill it in. I need to do it in the stream.
maybe there is a way to make it easier in the stream? or how do I fix my code

```
class Lesson_Stream6 {
//        # Name Surname Marks
//        1 Mike Scott [4,5,5]
//        2 Joe Jones [1,2,3]
//        3 Ann Fleming [3,3,3]
    public static void main(String[] args) {
String path1 = "C:\\Users\\Professional\\IdeaProjects\\Lesson\\src\\StreamAPI\\FileStream";
        List<String> fileLineName = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> fileLineNameSurname = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> stream1 = Files.lines(Paths.get(path1)).toList();
        String[] arr =  new String[stream1.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < stream1.size(); i++) {
            arr[i] = stream1.get(i);
        }
        List<String>NameSurname = Stream.of(arr)
                .filter( line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
                .map( l -> l.split(" ")[1] + l.split(" ")[2])
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<Student6>student4s = Stream.of(arr)
                .filter( line -> !line.startsWith("#"))
                .map( l -> {
                    String s = l.split(" ")[3];
                    String[] chars = s.split("");
                    Integer[] integers = new Integer[3];

                    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
                        if (chars[i].matches("[0-9]")) {
                            int c = 0;
                            integers[c++] = Integer.parseInt(chars[i]);
                        }
                    }
                   out.println(Arrays.toString(integers));
                    return new Student6(Integer.parseInt(l.split(" ")[0]), l.split(" ")[1], l.split(" ")[2],
                            new Integer[]{1, 1, 1});

                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        out.println(student4s.get(1).Name);
    }
}
class Student6 {

    int ID;
    String Name;
    String Surname;
    Integer [] marks;

    public Student6(int ID, String name, String surname, Integer[] marks) {
        this.ID = ID;
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        this.marks = marks;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the same question you asked previously? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76206869/read-part-of-the-file-using-stream

Comment: Don’t post the same question again. Improve your first question.

Comment: You can read a line from a file, so all you really need to do is to parse a single line. `String s = "1 Mike Scott [4,5,5]"` maybe if you reduce your question to just that. eg "How can I parse the array from this string?"